# Pandas dataframe - Difference between using loc and query

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe,df that looks like
[image: df]

I need to add a column `Weekday` to it, which is obtained through the index.

What is the difference between using

```
df['Weekday']=df.index.weekday
```

and

```
df.loc[:,'Weekday'] = df.index.weekday
```

Comment: In this case, nothing.

Answer (score 2):

In this case , you wont have any issues.

But is it advisable to use .loc functionality.

You can read the difference in detailed [here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/)